# How to set Time zone to TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Karachi" in Django Project?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, utc, django-timezone

I want to change the timezone of my django project to Asia/Karachi. I have added this in my settings.py file:

```
TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Karachi"
```

Time zone of my postgres is also set to Asia/Karachi.
But still when I create the objects, the time zone of DateTimeField is set to UTC.

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

Now when I create the object of MyClass, created_at and updated_at are storing Time with UTC timezone. Why is this so and how can I fix it?
Edit:
In my drf interface, I can see the time zone in Asia/Karachi. But when I check time zone in shell, it gives time zone in UTC.
[image]

In python shell:
[image]

Comment: The Second Note might helpful in this link, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add

Comment: This is by design. See the first sentence of the [timezone documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/): "When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms."

Comment: Your output looks like things are working exactly as they should. You have UTC times in your database and they're translated to the Karachi TZ when outputting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.py file, you can set the `TIME_ZONE`

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Karachi'
```

You might need to set `USE_TZ` as well.

```
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: I have set it already, but still Django is using UTC Timezone

Comment: What makes your think so? Did you try to get the data from django?

Comment: yes, I am checking the time zone of created_at from python shell.
It returns this:
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 15, 12, 39, 46, 855489, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

Comment: Are you using DRF? Or django itself only?

Comment: yes I am using DRF

Comment: Are you using django 4.0 ? Then you need to set `USE_TZ` to True as well.

Comment: I am using Django version 4.1.7

Comment: yes I am setting USE_TZ to true. Can you plz check my question? I have updated it.

Comment: Oh, man. Shell is just showing the data by default timezone. You don't have to worry about that. Because the frontend will get the time with right timezone you set.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer now?